# Generic view for saving multiple model instances

Tags: django-rest-framework

Django REST offers the [`ListCreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) which allows listing instances of a certain model via GET and creating a single instance via POST. It is based on `ListModelMixin` and `CreateModelMixin` and is very much what I need, except that I want to save a *list* of instances instead of only one instance per POST request.

Before I go ahead implementing an already existing feature, I would like to know if Django REST already offers something that I would call `ListCreateMultipleAPIView` or `CreateModelsMixin`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST framework doesn't offer such features. However, you will find some third parties do such as https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk